# MySQL which connection am I connected to?

Tags: mysql

I've downloaded MySQL yesterday. I am new to this.

I am now in MySQL terminal session. MySQL Workbench shows 3 connections I created. How do I check which connection I am using in MySQL terminal?

Comment: What do you mean, *"Workbench shows 3 connections I created"* ...?  Shows them how? You created how?  By "mysql terminal" do you mean the command line client?  It's not at all clear just what you are asking.

Comment: Once I open MySQLWorkbench, it right away shows MySQL Connections. I set up a new connection with a connection name, method, hostname, username ,password and schema. That's how I created a new connection. For mysql terminal, I meant MySQL prompt, which is mysql>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this command in the terminal.

```
 SHOW PROCESSLIST
```

It will show all the connections. The one that's running the command you just issued is the one associated with the terminal.

Comment: It still does not show my connection. For example, if MySQL Workbench shows 3 connections: A,B,C, the command you gave me does not specify which connection I am using of the 3 connections I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Use the hostname variable to determine which server you're connected to:

```
select @@hostname;
```